# How to disable Redis cache with Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-test, spring-data-redis, spring-cache

With Spring Boot 2.1 I am defining a RedisCacheManager bean in a configuration file, with Java configuration. Everything works correctly but I would like sometimes to disable it, for instance in the tests. Spring Boot provides the `spring.cache.type=NONE` to disable caching, as per this [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-caching.html#boot-features-caching-provider-none). However, this property will not work because I already define a CacheManager, and as such Spring Boot will not configure the NoOpCacheManager I would like there (there is a `@ConditionalOnMissingBean(CacheManager.class)` on the `NoOpCacheConfiguration` which has lower precedence than `RedisCacheConfiguration`).

When defining caches, whatever the provider (for intance Caffeine), we usually define them as beans, which are afterwards resolved by Spring Boot's auto-configuration into a `SimpleCacheManager`. 
For instance

```
    @Bean
    public Cache myCache() {
        return new CaffeineCache(
                "my-cache",
                Caffeine.newBuilder()
                        .maximumSize(10)
                        .build());
    }
```

Unfortunately this is not possible with Redis, because its `Cache` implementation, `RedisCache`, is not public.

Another thing we like to do is to define a bean `CacheManagerCustomizer<?>`, for instance with Caffeine

```
    @Bean
    public CacheManagerCustomizer<CaffeineCacheManager> caffeineCacheManager() {
        return cacheManager -> cacheManager
                .setCaffeine(Caffeine.newBuilder()
                        .expireAfterWrite(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES));
    }
```

Again this is not possible with Redis, as `RedisCacheManager` is **immutable**.

So the only solution right now is to create our own RedisCacheManager, but this prevent the usage of `spring.cache.type: NONE`.

So here is my question. What is the best way to configure a Redis cache with Spring Boot so that we can disable it as needed ?

Comment: you can ignore every `Bean` that you don't need in test profile with `@Profile("!test")`

Answer (score 13):

I had a requirement to enable/disable Redis auto configuration from `spring.cache.type` property. The below code solved my issue. This might help for anyone who want to disable/enable redis just by changing single property, in my case it is `spring.cache.type=redis`. Below are the major configurations.

```java
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {RedisAutoConfiguration.class})
public class SpringBootApp extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

}
```

```java
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "spring", name = "cache.type", havingValue = "redis")
@Configuration
@Import({ RedisAutoConfiguration.class })
public class ApplicationRedisConfig {

}
```

To enable auto configuration from `application.yaml`

```yaml
spring:
  cache:
    type: redis
  redis.host: redis
```

Health check gives below response when redis is not available which shows that auto configuration has been included.

```json
{
  "status": "DOWN",
  "details": {
    "diskSpace": {
      "status": "UP",
      "details": {
        "total": 486730272768,
        "free": 216405499904,
        "threshold": 10485760
      }
    },
    "db": {
      "status": "UP",
      "details": {
        "database": "PostgreSQL",
        "hello": 1
      }
    },
    "elasticsearch": {
      "status": "UP"
    },
    "redis": {
      "status": "DOWN",
      "details": {
        "error": "org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Unable to connect to Redis; nested exception is io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to redis:6379"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To disable auto configuration from `application.yaml`

```yaml
spring:
  cache:
    type: simple
  redis.host: redis
```

Health check gives below response which shows redis has been excluded from auto configuration.

```json
{
  "status": "UP",
  "details": {
    "diskSpace": {
      "status": "UP",
      "details": {
        "total": 486730272768,
        "free": 215928782848,
        "threshold": 10485760
      }
    },
    "db": {
      "status": "UP",
      "details": {
        "database": "PostgreSQL",
        "hello": 1
      }
    },
    "elasticsearch": {
      "status": "UP"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: very clean and straightforward solution, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

exclude attribute of the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation, something like: `@SpringBootApplication( exclude = { RedisAutoConfiguration.class } )`

and 
set: `spring.data.redis.repositories.enabled=false`

Comment: I would prefer not to rely on configuration exclusion, since it might break parts of our application. For instance if we want to inject the `RedisCacheManager` somewhere (for whatever reason),  the application would fail. `spring.cache.type: NONE` let us do that

Comment: Yes, thanks. So finally, I added 3 properties to make it work:   `spring.cache.type: simple, spring.data.redis.repositories.enabled: false, spring.autoconfigure.exclude: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.RedisAutoConfiguration`. Also I added a `CacheManager` bean to test config to let the cache be configured (as well as adding `@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "redis.host")` to the production config)

Answer (score 0):

You can use resilience4j-spring-boot2 dependency with
org.springframework.cache.annotation.CachingConfigurer.
this solution will work with the latest Spring-boot version 6.x.
it worked for me.
**Below are code snippet:**

**Pom.xml:**

```
<dependency>
<groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
<artifactId>resilience4j-spring-boot2</artifactId>
 <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**Cache config class:**

```
package com.redis.sample;
    import org.springframework.cache.annotation.CachingConfigurer;
    import org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheErrorHandler;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

    @Configuration
    public class CachingConfiguration implements CachingConfigurer        {  
        @Override
        public CacheErrorHandler errorHandler() {
            return new CustomCacheErrorHandler();
        }
    }
```

**CustomCacheErrorHandler class:**

```
package com.redis.sample;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.cache.Cache;
import org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheErrorHandler;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class CustomCacheErrorHandler implements CacheErrorHandler {
    
      
    
     
    @Override
    public void handleCacheGetError(RuntimeException exception, Cache cache, Object key) {
        //do something as per usecase
    }

    @Override
    public void handleCachePutError(RuntimeException exception, Cache cache, Object key, Object value) {
        //do something as per usecase
    }

    @Override
    public void handleCacheEvictError(RuntimeException exception, Cache cache, Object key) {
        //do something as per usecase
    }

    @Override
    public void handleCacheClearError(RuntimeException exception, Cache cache) {
        //do something as per usecase
    }
}
```

**CircuitBreakerConfig.java config class**
package com.redis.sample;

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import io.github.resilience4j.circuitbreaker.CircuitBreaker;
import io.github.resilience4j.circuitbreaker.CircuitBreakerRegistry;
@Configuration
public class CircuitBreakerConfig {

    @Bean
    public CircuitBreakerRegistry circuitBreakerRegistry() {
        io.github.resilience4j.circuitbreaker.CircuitBreakerConfig config =  io.github.resilience4j.circuitbreaker.CircuitBreakerConfig.custom()
                .failureRateThreshold(6)
                .permittedNumberOfCallsInHalfOpenState(2)
                .slidingWindowSize(5)
                .minimumNumberOfCalls(5)
                .build();
        return CircuitBreakerRegistry.of(config);
    }
    
     
    @Bean
     public CircuitBreaker defaultCircuitBreaker() {
        io.github.resilience4j.circuitbreaker.CircuitBreakerConfig config = io.github.resilience4j.circuitbreaker.CircuitBreakerConfig.custom()
                .minimumNumberOfCalls(2)
                .build();
        return CircuitBreaker.of("default", config);
     }
}
```